# how to set image Aspect ratio to 100 % in Powerpoint 2007 using vba?

Tags: vba, powerpoint, powerpoint-2007

I am working on automation tool. I want to set image Aspect ratio to 100 % on each slide.
Is there any property for that in vba?

Thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

```
Option Explicit

Sub Sample()
    Dim shp As Shape

    Set shp = ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("Picture 1")

    With shp
        .ScaleHeight 1, msoTrue
        .ScaleWidth 1, msoTrue
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks Siddharth. This is what i want. Thanks a ton